# d3 v4 version of stack function x and y

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am converting some v2 code to v4 and I am stuck at this point. where does the x an y functions go for v4? Also is this the right way to create nested values? Thanks

```
 d3.stack()
  .offset(d3.stackOffsetSilhouette)
  .value(function(d) { return d.values; })
  .x(function(d) { return d.date; })
  .y(function(d) { return d.value; });
var nest = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) { return d.key; });
var layers = stack(nest.entries(mainVal));
```

Edited to add full code. Everything has been migrated to v4 but I'm just not sure about that section since layers is returning as an empty array.

```
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>


<div class="chart">
</div>

<script>

chart("data.json", "orange");

var datearray = [];
var colorrange = [];


function chart(jsonpath, color) {

if (color == "blue") {
  colorrange = ["#045A8D", "#2B8CBE", "#74A9CF", "#A6BDDB", "#D0D1E6", "#F1EEF6"];
}
else if (color == "pink") {
  colorrange = ["#980043", "#DD1C77", "#DF65B0", "#C994C7", "#D4B9DA", "#F1EEF6"];
}
else if (color == "orange") {
  colorrange = ["#B30000", "#E34A33", "#FC8D59", "#FDBB84", "#FDD49E", "#FEF0D9"];
}
strokecolor = colorrange[0];

var format = d3.timeFormat("%m/%d/%y");

var margin = {top: 20, right: 40, bottom: 30, left: 30};
var width = document.body.clientWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var tooltip = d3.select("body")
.append("div")
.attr("class", "remove")
.style("position", "absolute")
.style("z-index", "20")
.style("visibility", "hidden")
.style("top", "30px")
.style("left", "55px");

var x = d3.scaleTime()
.range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
.range([height-10, 0]);

var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
.range(colorrange);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
.scale(x)
.tickFormat(d3.timeWeeks);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
.scale(y);

var yAxisr = d3.axisRight()
.scale(y);

var stack = d3.stack()
.offset(d3.stackOffsetSilhouette)
.value(function(d) { return d.values; });

var nest = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) { return d.key; });

var area = d3.area()
.curve(d3.curveCardinal)
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y0(function(d) { return y(d.y0); })
.y1(function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); });

var svg = d3.select(".chart").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var graph = d3.json(jsonpath, function(data) {
var parsed = [];
var mainVal = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i ++) {
var timeData = JSON.parse(data[i]).default.timelineData;

parsed.push(timeData);
}

for (var j = 0; j < parsed.length; j++) {
for (var k = 0; k < parsed[j].length; k++) {
obj = {};
  var date = new Date(1000*parsed[j][k].time);
  obj.value = parsed[j][k].value[0];
  obj.date = date;
  obj.key = 'arr' + j;
  mainVal.push(obj);
  }
  }

mainVal.forEach(function(d) {
d.date = d.date;
d.value = +d.value;
});

var layers = nest.entries(mainVal);

x.domain(d3.extent(mainVal, function(d) {
return d.date; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(mainVal, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; })]);

svg.selectAll(".layer")
  .data(layers)
.enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "layer")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
  console.log(d.values); 
    console.log(area(d.values));
    return area(d.values); })
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return z(i); });


svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ", 0)")
  .call(yAxisr);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

svg.selectAll(".layer")
.attr("opacity", 1)
.on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
  svg.selectAll(".layer").transition()
  .duration(250)
  .attr("opacity", function(d, j) {
    return j != i ? 0.6 : 1;
})})

.on("mousemove", function(d, i) {
  mousex = d3.mouse(this);
  mousex = mousex[0];
  var invertedx = x.invert(mousex);
  invertedx = invertedx.getMonth() + invertedx.getDate();
  var selected = (d.values);
  for (var k = 0; k < selected.length; k++) {
    datearray[k] = selected[k].date
    datearray[k] = datearray[k].getMonth() + datearray[k].getDate();
  }

  mousedate = datearray.indexOf(invertedx);
  pro = d.values[mousedate].value;

  d3.select(this)
  .classed("hover", true)
  .attr("stroke", strokecolor)
  .attr("stroke-width", "0.5px"), 
  tooltip.html( "<p>" + d.key + "<br>" + pro + "</p>"      ).style("visibility", "visible");

})
.on("mouseout", function(d, i) {
 svg.selectAll(".layer")
  .transition()
  .duration(250)
  .attr("opacity", "1");
  d3.select(this)
  .classed("hover", false)
  .attr("stroke-width", "0px"), tooltip.html( "<p>" + d.key + "<br>" + pro + "</p>" ).style("visibility", "hidden");
  })

  var vertical = d3.select(".chart")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "remove")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("z-index", "19")
    .style("width", "1px")
    .style("height", "380px")
    .style("top", "10px")
    .style("bottom", "30px")
    .style("left", "0px")
    .style("background", "#fff");

  d3.select(".chart")
  .on("mousemove", function(){  
     mousex = d3.mouse(this);
     mousex = mousex[0] + 5;
     vertical.style("left", mousex + "px" )})
  .on("mouseover", function(){  
     mousex = d3.mouse(this);
     mousex = mousex[0] + 5;
     vertical.style("left", mousex + "px")});
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: can you place your full code and the HTML as well?

Comment: I've added the full code @ZombieChowder